# Load Server URL dicom files inside Imebra in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, dicom, imebra

I am using https://imebra.com/  in my application, when I load a local files it reading the DICOM file and I am able to see the Image. when, I am  sending Cloud url path to imebra It is showing an error and below I shared sample code.I want to send a single or multiple url to Imebra. I don't know how to proceed.

```
 let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "dcm") // i want to send url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ivmartel/dwv/master/tests/data/bbmri-53323851.dcm) here
 let dataSet = try ImebraCodecFactory.load(fromFile: filepath)

  _ = try dataSet.getString(ImebraTagId(group: 0x10, tag: 0x10), elementNumber: 0, defaultValue: "")

  _ = try dataSet.getString(ImebraTagId(group: 0x10, tag: 0x10), elementNumber: 1, defaultValue: "")
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I integrated libimebra.a file in my project. I have followed added Search paths in build settings and added in link binary with libraries as well. Despite all that I am getting below error "Use of unresolved identifier 'ImebraCodecFactory'". any help or suggestion please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Imebra can load local DICOM files or from remote PACS (using the DIMSE protocol).

Imebra cannot load an image directly from an URL because it uses a posix call to open the local file.

To open a file from an URL you should first load the remote file. See this answer [Simple Swift file download with URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26408613/147763) to see how to load a file to a local temporary file.

Alternatively, you could load the file to a NSData object and pass its content to an Imebra Memory object, then pass to ImebraCodecFactory a StreamReader using a MemoryStreamInput.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Imebra